# Is there an R function to calculate percentages?

Tags: r, dplyr, percentage

I have a DF that looks like the following called crash_stats_TA.

| TA_code | TA_name | Crashes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 061 | Grey | 126 |
| 062 | Buller | 345 |
| 063 | Westland | 24 |
| 064 | Timaru | 112 |

I am trying to create a new column called crashes_perc using mutate.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
library(dplyr) # data manipulation

crash_stats_TA <- crash_stats_TA %>%
  group_by(TA_code, TA_name) %>%
  mutate(crashes_perc = round(Crashes/sum(Crashes, na.rm = T)*100,2))
```

However, this returns a new colum of crashes_perc with values of 100 for each TA_code and TA_name, so every area has 100. Like so:

[image: df]

What would be the reason for this.
Not really sure how to go about properly excuting this step

Comment: Based on the data showed, you have only 1 Crashe per group.  Thus it is 100% i..e you `sum` returns the same value.  Maybe your logic needs to be different

Answer (score 3):

Using `scales::percent`,

```
crash %>%
  mutate(crashes_perc = scales::percent(Crashes/sum(Crashes, na.rm = T)))

  TA_code TA_name  Crashes crashes_perc
    <int> <chr>      <int> <chr>       
1      61 Grey         126 20.8%       
2      62 Buller       345 56.8%       
3      63 Westland      24 4.0%        
4      64 Timaru       112 18.5%
```

Add `group_by` if there is enough size of sample per groups.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the 100% is because there is only value 'Crashes' per group and the `sum` returns the same value.  Instead, it should be without any grouping

```
library(dplyr)
crash_stats_TA %>% 
  mutate(crashes_perc = round(Crashes/sum(Crashes, na.rm = TRUE)*100,2))
```

-output

```
TA_code  TA_name Crashes crashes_perc
1      61     Grey     126        20.76
2      62   Buller     345        56.84
3      63 Westland      24         3.95
4      64   Timaru     112        18.45
```

---

In `base R`, use `proportions`

```
crash_stats_TA$crashes_perc <- with(crash_stats_TA, round(100 * 
         proportions(Crashes), 2))
```

#### data

```
crash_stats_TA <- structure(list(TA_code = 61:64, TA_name = c("Grey", "Buller", 
"Westland", "Timaru"), Crashes = c(126L, 345L, 24L, 112L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```